# iOS in-app purchase - "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error - Users still being charged

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a live app on the app store, and recently (last couple of days) I've got many complaints from users, claiming that after in-app purchasing, they are being charged but do not receive the coins I offer.

When I look into the users' logs, I see that the users that report this issue received an error message of **"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"** from the in-app purchasing code.
By this, I mean that **"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"** is the error message printed from this code:

```
NSString* errorMessage = [transaction.error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];  
NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
```

Where transaction is of type SKPaymentTransaction.

Is it possible that I get this error from the in-app purchasing service **while the user is still being charged?**

My code obviously does not award them the coins in case it gets such an error.

It's worth noting that while some get this issue, many others are able to purchase the exact same in-app items and offers.

Is this a known issue of some sort? Did anyone run into it or have any idea how it could happen?